# Elements of Programming 6.4 Two-shot and k-shot strategy algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Finding it hard to understand the two shot and k-shot strategy algorithms. Here is the question again:

Q1) arr is an array of length n. Compute max of A[j0]-A[i0] + A[j1]-A[i1] subject to condition that
    i0 < j0 < i1 < j1

Ans)  We can do single-shot (i.e. max profit buy-sell stock) in O(n) . We can apply the same technique
     to find max from 0.. j and max from j..n. It would be O(n2) solution.

```
 Elements of Programming interviews book suggests a way of doing this in O(n) time by:
 doing a forward iteration and storing solution for A[0:j] such that 1<=j<=n-1  and then a backward iteration for A[j:n-1] such that 0<=j<=n-2 and then combining the two results.  Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?
```

Q2) How would you do k-shot ?

thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**

Let's solve this easier problem in `O(n)` first: find `i0 < j0` such that `A[j0] - A[i0]` is maximized.

For each `j0`, we need to find the minimum of `0, 1, ..., j0 - 1` and compare `A[j0] - this minimum` to the global max. This is easily done by just computing the minimum so far as we go along.

Now, for your original problem, we also need `i1 < j1` such that `A[j1] - A[i1]` is maximized. Or, for each `i1`, we need to find `j1 > i1` such that `A[j1] - A[i1]` is maximized.

Let:

```
min[i] = minimum in [0, ..., i]
max[i] = maximum in [i, ..., n - 1]
```

So now we need `i < j` such that `A[i] - min[i - 1] + max[j + 1] - A[j]` is maximized. This can be done by computing, in `O(n)`:

```
max1[i] = max{A[1] - min[0], A[2] - min[1], ..., A[i] - min[i - 1]}
max2[i] = max{max[i + 1] - A[i], max[i] - A[i - 1], ...max[1] - A[0]}
```

Then just take the max of `max1[i - 1] + max2[i]` over all `i >= 2`.

Comment: @adne - you're welcome, but I don't know how to do Q2. It's ok not to accept this yet if you want to wait for an answer to that as well.